# If I don't have an EULA, can I just display a general license?

Tags: licensing, commercial, eula

I wrote a library in Python and I want to have an EULA and agreement box to pop up upon opening the program for the first time, but I don't have a lawyer. I don't know much about terms and conditions, licensing, privacy policies, etc. I picked around on the web and I decided to use the LGPL 3.0 license (Lesser General Public License 3.0). Is it okay if I display that upon startup instead of an actual EULA to make sure people using the library understand redistribution priveleges? But then if I do that, how do I present who owns the original version of the software? It's all a jumbled mess and I don't know what to do.

Comment: What is your reason for wanting to show a dialog that nobody ever bothers to read anyway? You can perfectly have a program without an EULA and associated agreement box. In fact, most open-source software does without it.

Comment: Installing libraries seems pretty unusual.

Comment: It almost sounds like you've assumed you have to display some kind of legal document to the user and are asking what documents are acceptable; you don't have to display anything. If you need to understand *all* the implications of showing nothing vs an EULA vs a copyleft license, you really need to have a long conversation with a lawyer. If you can narrow this down to something feasibly specific like "can I use the LGPL without showing it to the user?" then we could help.

Comment: @Ixrec I was thinking I should at least have a privacy policy, because the library is more like an API. It's a web crawler that requires an account to access a website, like a bot, but to get an account it needs possible private information (password, sometimes email) and I'd like to explain to the user that their information is only being stored on their local hard drive, as well as the fact that the program only runs on Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux/UNIX.